# Using a jsp bean in a session

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I am using a JSP bean and when I do an assignment to a new object, it gets over-written on a submit to the previous object.

```
<jsp:useBean id="base" class="com.example.StandardBase" scope="session" />
...
//base object id  = 396
base = new Base()
//base object id = 1000
```

and on a resubmit of the page I get

```
<jsp:useBean id="base" class="com.example.StandardBase" scope="session" />
//base object id = 396
```

Is there a way to tell JSP to do a new assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I think `base = new Base()` does not update the reference stored in the session scope. Therefore, the bean you created with the initial `<jsp:useBean/>` is still around while the one you create manually, and then updated, isn't.

Get rid of `base = new Base()` and you should be fine.

If you insist upon updating it, you use [`HttpSession.setAttribute()`](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)). Like so:

```
session.setAttribute("bean", bean);
```

I believe the variable `session` is automatically created and initialized for you by the JSP engine.

Comment: this is what i figured(after the fact).  Is there a way to overwrite the reference?

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to new the bean yourself. Let JSP do that for you

Answer (score 0):

would changing scope from session to request fix this for you?